# data type of each characters in a varchar T-sql

Tags: sql, t-sql, sqldatatypes

I'm curious on the data I get from someone. Most of the time I need to get 3 integers then a space then eight integers.

And The integration created a column varchar(20) ... Don't doubt it works, but that gives me some matching errors.

Because of this, I'd like to know what is the data type of the characters on each row.

For exemple : 0 is for integer, s for space, a for char, * for specific

```
AWB             | data type
---------------------------------
012 12345678    | 000s00000000
9/5 ab0534      | 0*0saa0000
```

I'd like to know if there is a function or a formula to get this kind of results.
Right after I'll be able to group by this column and finally be able to check how good is the data quality.

I don't know if there is a specific word for what I tried to explain, so excuse me if this is a duplicate of a post, I didn't find it.

Thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing built-in, but you might use an approach like this:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,AWB VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('012 12345678')
,('9/5 ab0534');

WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT t.ID
          ,t.AWB
          ,A.Nmbr 
          ,C.YourMask
    FROM @tbl t
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP (DATALENGTH(t.AWB)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM master..spt_values) A(Nmbr)
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT SUBSTRING(t.AWB,A.Nmbr,1)) B(SingleCharacter)
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE WHEN B.SingleCharacter LIKE '[0-9]' THEN '0'
                             WHEN B.SingleCharacter LIKE '[a-z]' THEN 'a'
                             WHEN B.SingleCharacter = ' ' THEN 's'
                             ELSE '*' END) C(YourMask)
)
SELECT ID
      ,AWB
      ,(
        SELECT YourMask 
        FROM cte cte2
        WHERE cte2.ID=cte.ID
        ORDER BY cte2.Nmbr
        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE  
       ).value('.','nvarchar(max)') YourMaskConcatenated
FROM cte
GROUP BY ID,AWB;
```

The idea in short:

The `cte` will create a derived set of your table.
The first `CROSS APPLY` will create a list of numbers as long as the current `AWB` value.
The second `CROSS APPLY` will read each character separately.
The third `CROSS APPLY` will finally use some rather simple logic to translate your values to the *mask* you expect.

The final `SELECT` will then use `GROUP BY` and a correlated sub-query with `FOR XML` to get the mask characters re-concatenated (With version v2017+ this would be easier calling `STRING_AGG()`).

Comment: Huge thank, firstly for the result, secondly for the explanations. I'm pretty bad at CROSS APPLY use.

Comment: @ValentinC Oh, that's pretty simple: `APPLY` can be seen as *row-wise-join*. Other than a *normal JOIN*, which is a *conjunction of sets*,  this is computed *row-by-row* approach, hence we can use the row's values and deal with them.